# User Defined Functions show #NAME? Error on Workbook Startup

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a user defined function in Excel 2010 that looks at a range of data and sums it (the actual code is irrelevant to this problem). It normally works fine, except whenever I make a change to my source code or open the workbook for the first time. When this happens, every cell that uses the UDF has just a #NAME? error instead.

I have tried recalculating with the tool button, pressing F9, and entering a formula in a different cell and pressing enter.

What WILL make it work is selecting any of the UDF cells, clicking in the formula bar, then pressing enter (i.e. no changes made), then they all calculate properly. What ALSO works is going into the source code, making a simple change (e.g. adding a blank line in any module), THEN using any of the previously mentioned methods to trigger a recalculation event.

When I load the workbook, macros are initially disabled until I click the "Enable" button. It is at that point that the previously saved values convert to #NAME? error. It seems like it is something to do with this, but I do not have permissions to permanently allow macros where I work, and if another user opens it on his account, he will have the same problems I'm having now.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I did have the same problem once (in a corporate environment with virtual desktops hosted on a citrix farm). Do you mind checking if the following solves it. Navigate to `Data` ► `Connections` ► `Refresh All` ► `Refresh All`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with one of my macros which copies information from a range and pastes it to a table. Since the table in my case consists of serial numbers which all have either a 1 or a 2 in them, I added the following bit to my sub so that the error goes away:

```
    With .DataBodyRange
        .Replace What:="1", Replacement:="1"
        .Replace What:="2", Replacement:="2"
    End With
```

You could put something similar into the Worksheet_Activate function... I know, it's not a "real" answer and instead just works around the issue, but it does get the job done. Hopefully somebody can provide a better solution and we can both learn something.

Comment: I tried the find replace method and it did not work. I also tried using a macro to delete the last row in the spreadsheet and that just turned every instance of my formula to #VALUE. What is interesting is if I manually delete an empty row, everything recalculates properly. Why would manual work but a macro doing the exact same thing wouldn't?